# abort system call behaviour

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

I have  a parent process which is handling the signal `SIGCHLD`.
If I call `abort()` in the child process , the `SIGABRT` signal is raised in the child process.

My question is , at the time of child process core dumping , `SIGCHLD` signal will be sent to parent process or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SIGCHLD signal is *always* sent by the (unixoid at least) OS to your process as soon as the child dies - no matter of which reason it dies (because of SIGABRT or SIGSEGV, terminating regularly by calling exit or simply leaving main, ...).

You get some information about what happened in the child in the status variable you provide to the functions of the wait family, a small example you find e. g. [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html).